# How do I test validity of a model object only on update using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, rspec2

I have a profile model like so;

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true, on: :update
  validates :last_name, presence: true, on: :update
end
```

I am wanting to write some rspec tests to test the validation of first_name and last_name but I cannot see how to run `profile.should_not be_valid` only on update in a model test. Something like;

```
it "should be invalid without a first name on update" do
  profile = FactoryGirl.build :profile
  profile.first_name = nil
  profile_should_not be_valid
end
```

doesn't differentiate between an update or create action and I can't see anything in the rspec documentation about this. Surely it's a fairly common thing to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`be_valid` in rspec just calls `valid?` on the model.

```
profile = FactoryGirl.build :profile
```

This builds a new model instance for `Profile`, but does not commit it to the database. You would use this `profile` for your create test. Setting `:first_name` to `nil` should and calling `profile.should be_valid` should pass.

```
profile = FactoryGirl.create :profile
```

This builds **and inserts** the model instance for `Profile` into the database. You would use this `profile` for your update test. Setting `:first_name` to `nil` should and calling `profile.should be_valid` should **fail**.

Comment: OK, that's actually pretty simple and what I thought should happen. I had a few callbacks in my model (that I left out for simplicity) that were interfering with this.